# How to include all next page data within single PHP foreach loop using JSON data

Tags: php, json

I have a JSON file that limits me to 50 items per page, and there is a total of 818 for this one item.

I can pull the data from the first 50 individually.
I'm wondering if anyone knows how I can pull all of the additional pages too so they're all in one php request.

Does anyone happen to have an idea for a function or if statement that could help sort this out?

Example piece of json with limited amount of results (50 would be shown):

```
{
    "count": 818, 
    "max_per_page": 50, 
    "current_page": 1, 
    "links": [
        {
            "href": "http://domain.com/?page=2", 
            "rel": "next"
        }, 
        {
            "href": "http://domain.com/", 
            "rel": "prev"
        }
    ], 
    "results": [
        {
            "id": "1", 
            "href": "http://domain.com/23385", 
            "product_line": "A", 
            "departures_start_date": "2015-01-01", 
            "departures_end_date": "2017-12-24"
        }, 
        {
            "id": "2", 
            "href": "http://domain.com/22760", 
            "product_line": "B", 
            "departures_start_date": "2015-01-01", 
            "departures_end_date": "2017-12-16"
        }, 
        {
            "id": "3", 
            "href": "http://domain.com/22790", 
            "product_line": "C", 
            "departures_start_date": "2015-01-01", 
            "departures_end_date": "2017-12-30"
        }, 
    ]
}
```

Comment: how are you creating your `json` object in `php`?

Comment: We can suggest how to create a loop to retrieve all, but do you know how retrieve remaining json data?

Comment: Hey @roullie I am using GET and parsing it into variables and manually creating my own JSON file which is used for import. I'm basically stripping away parts I don't want to use and since this last piece of data I need has a paged json limit for 50 items per page I'm limited to access all the data easily.

Comment: Hey @fusion3k I believe I know how to retrieve the remaining json, the only thing I'd need to know is if using your loop would I use (when I get past 50) something like 51 instead of 1 which the next page would have '$productline = $loopresult['results']['51']['product_line'];'

Comment: Can you describe what exactly you are trying to accomplish? (cuz I'm sensing an XY problem here.) Are you retrieving the JSON with AJAX? and then load each 50-item set on clicking the page numbers? if you are doing it with AJAX, modify the AJAX callback function instead. This does't seem to me like a PHP question since you decide on what to pass back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you retrieve your data using `file_get_contents`, you can try this:

```
$array = array();
$page = 1;
while( $data = file_get_contents( '/Your/Path/Here?page=$page++' ) )
{
    $json = json_decode( $data, True );                                   #01
    foreach( $json['results'] as $row ) $array[] = $row;
}
```

At the end of the loop, the array will contain all elements:

```
[
    [
        "id": "1", 
        "href": "http://domain.com/23385", 
        (...)
    ], 
    [
        "id": "2", 
        "href": "http://domain.com/22760", 
        (...)
    ], 
    (...) 
]
```

If you prefer objects instead of arrays, you can omit `True` (#01) and then each row will be callable through `$row->id` instead of `$row['id']`

Comment: Hey Fusion3k, thanks for your input but sadly I believe I miss communicated.  I already have a foreach loop working similar to how you've described. I'm not using the file_get_contents though. The trouble I'm having is I can do a foreach loop and it will pull the first 50 items. However at the top it says the Paging limits to 50 each page and there is a total of 818 ids. That means I need to call 17 pages minimum to grab all the data.  I'm trying to see if I can make a function to run through all those pages so I can grab all 818 id's content such as the product_line and start and end dates.

Comment: For example if I used your `$array = array();
while( $data = file_get_contents( 'http://domain.com/?page=1' ) )
{
    $json = json_decode( $data, True );                                   #01
    foreach( $json['results'] as $row ) $array[] = $row;
}` and I wanted to store it in array like .= $array; so I could do another loop on page 2, 3, 4, all the way to the last page it detected.

Comment: use `$pagenum = 1; while( file_get_contents( 'domain.com/?page=$pagenum++'))` (without `;`!) my while loop stop when the content is empty, but do you know how detect last page. if you prefer, you can retrieve total pages (in this case `$totpag = ceil(818/50)`) and then use `for( $page=1; $page<=$totpag; $page++ )` instead of `while`. I've been clear?

Comment: Very helpful @fusion3k, thanks a ton! I wish I could rate up your answer but once I have rank I'll definitely rank it up. +1 thanks for your help

Comment: @user5706571 You're welcome. No matter about rating, but please mark the answer so the question can be archived ad closed